# Difference between concrete and specific

Tags: difference

In my dictionary, *concrete* means "existing in fact and not merely as a possibility", for example, *concrete evidence*. I was wondering if *concrete* in that sense is same as *specific*?

Comment: But they're not at all the same! Your usage of ***concrete*** is the figurative *existing in a material form, or **as an actual reality***, whereas your ***specific*** means *specially or peculiarly **pertaining to a certain thing** or class of things and constituting one of the characteristic features of this.* It just so happens that "evidence" can be qualified using either or both terms.

Comment: Is *imaginary* the opposite of *concrete*, and *general* the opposite of *specific*?

Comment: In some contexts, yes. But whereas *concrete* - or more often, ***hard** evidence* - is commonplace, I never heard of *imaginary evidence*. Come to that, [***specific** circumstantial evidence*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22specific+circumstantial+evidence%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is a fairly ordinary collocation, but I don't think it would be possible to refer to ***concrete** circumstantial evidence*.

Comment: What is the opposite of *particular*, same as that for *specific*?

Comment: As you said, *general* is often the opposite of *particular*. As can be seen in most written instances of [*...the **general**, not the **particular***...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+general+not+the+particular%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Then what is difference between *particular* and *specific*?

Comment: It all depends on the exact context. If I say *"This **particular** question is General Reference"*, probably the most obvious "opposite" is *"**All** questions are General Reference"*. As to the difference between *specific* and *particular*, they're effectively interchangeable synonyms in many contexts (but certainly not *all* contexts; true synonyms are exceptionally rare, if they exist at all).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Concrete* and *specific* mean very different things, although in some circumstances they may both be applied to communicate somewhat similar meanings.

*Specific* is approximately synonymous with *particular* or *individual*; its antonym is usually *general*. A general property or attribute applies to all members of a class; a specific property or attribute applies to only some members or one member of the class.

*Concrete* is approximately synonymous with *tangible* or *material*; its antonym is usually *abstract*. An abstract entity has no physical existence, it is a mental construction, an idea; but a concrete entity is, in some sense, present to the senses.

The overlap arises when we are contrasting a physical ‘thing’ with the non-physical ‘class’ or ‘category’ to which it belongs. For instance, ‘human’ signifies those *general* qualities which are shared by all individual persons, or the *abstract* quality of being human, a member of the class *homo sapiens*; but an individual person is both *specific*, distinguishable from every other person, and *concrete*, possessing physical existence;.